# Manipulate browser settings from command line via bash?

Tags: bash, firefox, command-line

I would like be able to change some Firefox setting via command line with a bash script, can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Here Is An Example Script For Your Request:

```
#!/bin/bash
 cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/
 sed -i 's/user_pref("'$1'",.*);/user_pref("'$1'",'$2');/' user.js
 grep -q $1 user.js || echo "user_pref(\"$1\",$2);" >> user.js
```

You need to edit the mozilla path to your profile dir if the path on first line is wrong.

### Find Alot More Info In URL Below:

[Using command line options for Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)